# Database connections not close on birt when errors occurs in building

Tags: sql-server-2008, tomcat, oracle10g, birt

I'm using BIRT (4.1)

Connections to database are not closed when problem occurs in the build of report.

So many connections are open in database, that causes performance trouble.

Here is the code I made to deal with it. But it doesn't work:

```
IRunAndRenderTask task;
task.setRenderOption(renderOption);
try {
            task.getAppContext().put("OdaJDBCDriverPassInConnectionCloseAfterUse", true);
            task.setErrorHandlingOption(task.CANCEL_ON_ERROR);

            task.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);          
        }
        if (task.getErrors() != null && task.getErrors().size() > 0) {
            logger.error(task.getErrors().toString());              
            //task.cancel();
            task.close();
            task=null;          
            throw new Exception("Somes errors append during birt report gerenation");
        }
```

Comment: Have you thought about moving your task.close() code into the catch block? Does the exception print in the catch block? Maybe you should also try adding a debug statement to the if (task.getErrors()) conditional to see if it is executing.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe task.getErrors() is returning null thus resulting in close() not being called. I agree with @David.  You should have the whole block of code between the if statements inside the try catch block.

Comment: I put  break points into the block, and the statements (close , cancel) are correctly executed. (In BIRT when exceptions occur during the generation, no exception is thrown, but the errors are in the task.geterrors() )